# Error While Updating Rasbian from Jessie to Stretch

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-jessie

I've been using this guide to update my Rasbian version:

http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2017/10/26/upgrade-raspian-jessie-to-stretch/

However, after changing the files to use "Stretch" rather than "Jessie", on trying to use sudo apt-get update, I get this error:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'staging/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no officially supported upgrade.

Expert users can upgrade, provided they are prepared to handle the issues.

If you did this when Stretch was introduced, it may have worked, but there have been significant changes since.

Don't bother! Buster will be out in the next few months.

Incidentally the link you posted contains some very bad advice to run rpi-update.

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."