# RPi 2: Could not communicate with wpa-supplicant

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-buster, wpa-supplicant

Like the title, I updated the Raspbian from Jessie to Buster, and when I restarted my Pi 2 Model B, wlan0 suddenly not associated, I noticed that could be my Wifi dongle problem. But when I get to raspi-config in Terminal to change Wifi settings, it just threw me this error box "Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant"

P/S: Ethernet is still working properly,

Is this a system bug or just an error ? If that an error, how should I fix it ?

My Wifi dongle is TP-Link TP-WN725N Wireless N

Thank you [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJTq0.jpg)

Comment: Updating Rasbian from Jessie to Stretch didn't work - you have no chance with Buster.  [Error While Updating Rasbian from Jessie to Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99397/error-while-updating-rasbian-from-jessie-to-stretch)

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian is a flavor of Debian. Debian has a powerful package management system which can full upgrade from an old version to the next one, e.g. from version **Jessie** to version **Stretch**  but it cannot upgrade across two or more versions, e.g. from **Jessie** to  **Buster** (the successor of **Stretch**). To do such things you have first to upgrade to **Stretch** and then upgrade again to **Buster**. With each upgrade there are some settings left from the old version so an upgrade is not 100 % the same as a new installation. It is a good idea to make a new installation after an upgrade.

Anyway, this is said for Debian. For Raspbian there is no official support for upgrades by the Raspberry Pi Foundation. They say you should always start a new version from an image. For experienced user who can handle the upcoming problems it may be possible to do an upgrade. But I'm afraid you will not find much help about your problems because what you have done isn't defined and reproducible.